# python turtle fluctuation on write whats wrong?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I used "mypen.undo()" to avoid overwriting the score and hit points, but my turtle fluctuates on my screen (output). Somehow It gets refine when I remove a but it overwrites. Maybe it is about to "for" and "if". How do I avoid not overwriting and fluctuating(output) ??

```
import turtle
import math
import random
import winsound

#Collision Checking Goals
        if isCollision(player, goals[count]):
            goals[count].setposition(random.randint(-300,300), random.randint(-300, 300))
            goals[count].right(random.randint(0,360))
            score += 10


    #Move the wrongs
    for wcount in range(maxWrongs):
        wrongs[wcount].forward(3)

        #Boundary Checking
        if wrongs[wcount].xcor() > 290 or wrongs[wcount].xcor() < -290:
            wrongs[wcount].right(100)
        
        if wrongs[wcount].ycor() > 290 or wrongs[wcount].ycor() < -290:
            wrongs[wcount].right(100)
            
        #Collision Checking Wrongs
        if isCollision(player, wrongs[wcount]):
            wrongs[wcount].setposition(random.randint(-300,300), random.randint(-300, 300))
            wrongs[wcount].right(random.randint(0,360))
            
            score -= 20
            life -= 1

        #Draw the score on the screen
        mypen.undo()
        mypen.penup()
        mypen.hideturtle()
        mypen.setposition(-290,310)
        scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
        mypen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial",14,"normal"))

        #Draw the Life on the screen
        mypen.undo()
        mypen.penup()
        mypen.hideturtle()
        mypen.setposition(230,310)
        wlife = "Life: %s" %life
        mypen.write(wlife, False, align="left", font=("Arial",14,"normal"))

        if life<1:
            mypen.undo()
            mypen.penup()
            mypen.hideturtle()
            mypen.setposition(-140.951,-20.117)
            end = "END GAME"
            mypen.write(end, align="left", font=("Arial",40,"normal"))
            scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
            mypen.setposition(-90.540,-62.596)
            mypen.write(scorestring, align="left", font=("Arial",28,"normal"))
            turtle.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a proper minimal runnable code example, I can't give a definitive answer but based on what I see:

```
    mypen.undo()
    mypen.penup()
    mypen.hideturtle()
    mypen.setposition(-290,310)
    scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
    mypen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial",14,"normal"))
```

My suggestion is don't reuse `mypen`.  Instead create one for each static text element, e.g. `mypen_score`.  Position that turtle *once* in the initialization of your code.  Hide it, and leave it's pen up.  In the running portion of your code, you only need that turtle to undo and write, nothing more.

```
# initialization time
mypen_score = Turtle()
mypen_score.hideturtle()
mypen_score.penup()
mypen_score.setposition(-290, 310)
mypen_score.write("Score: 0", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))

   # main loop time
    mypen_score.undo()
    scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
    mypen_score.write(scorestring, font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
```

Ditto for "life", etc.